# Adapt Height of the Chart (Highcharts)

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am trying to adapt the height of my chart (highcharts) to 150px. The highest data point of the chart should have a height of 150px while the others should have a percentual adapted height of these 150px. My problem is that the highest bar always got heights around 110px, 120px or sometimes 150px. Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

[Screenshot of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCC73.png)

**My JSON:**

```
chart: {
     type: 'column',
     className: 'chart-wrapper',
     spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
     margin: [0, 40, 0, 40],
     height: 450,
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [
    {
         name: 'Gains',
         type: undefined,
         data: [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 12], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1]],
         // data: data,
         color: '#63CCA6',
         borderRadius: 4,
         maxPointWidth: 10,
         pointPadding: 0
     }
],
legend: {
     enabled: false,
},
title: {
     text: null
},
yAxis: {
     gridLineColor: 'transparent',
     className: 'axis-y',
     minPadding: 0,
     maxPadding: 0,
     height: 150,
     top: 196,
     min: 0,
     title: {
          text: null
     },
     labels: {
          enabled: false
     },
},
xAxis: {
     tickLength: 0,
     className: 'axis-x',
     categories: dates,
     crosshair: {
          className: 'crosshair',
          dashStyle: 'Dash',
          snap: false,
          width: 1
     },
     labels: {
          useHTML: true,
          autoRotation: [0],
          step: 2,
          formatter: function () {
               return moment(this.value).format('MM/YYYY');
          },
     },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `max` and disable `endOnTick` option:

```
yAxis: {
    height: 150,
    endOnTick: false,
    max: 12,
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/12r6z4j9/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

Comment: the problem is that my highest data point varies, it's not always 12. Nevertheless your solution works for me when I kick the max. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Dominik, You can also dynamically set the `max` property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rk4pzcgx/, but it seems that all you have to do is set `endOnTick: false`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oe63yx71/